# Check if view reaches the center of the screen iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am trying to implement an expandable view on iOS using objective-c. initially the view's size is 1pt and all contents are hidden. It will expand to a bigger size and all contents will be visible when the view is scrolled up and reached the center of the screen. How can I create a listener to detect when the view is at the center of the screen?

Comment: How are you changing the size of the view?  What is your view?  A scrollview?

Comment: It's a collection view, and the app looks more like a list of horizontal table cells. The view is in between other collection view cells. For changing the size I am trying to change the frame size after it reaches the center.

Comment: It isn't really clear what you are trying to achieve, but you may be able to use the delegate methods from the collection view's scrollview

Comment: So its basically like this picture [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/Art/tvcellstyle_subtitle.jpg). What I wanted is that "Stones" is hidden (or 1pt height) initially. But once the "Stones" has been scrolled up to the center of the screen, it expands and shows its content so user can see "Stones". I will have a look into the scrollview

Comment: You can use the contentOffset property in UIScrollView to check the position during scrolling.

Comment: Can this return the coordinate of a specific indexpath in the collection view thought?

Comment: nvm, I tried to listen to the difference between contentOffset.y and view.frame.origin.y. It worked! thanks @GurjinderSingh